# What is the case of using 'public'

Tags: java

Java has different access levels for fields:

- `public`
- `protected`
- `default`
- `private`

Due to **encapsulation** concept we always trying to use `private` modifier with getters and setters of needed access level. It has various advantages shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1568230/7147393) answer. Since getters and setters are so cool, when should we **prefer** `public/protected/default Object field;` to `private Object field;` with `public/protected/default` getters and setters?

**Clarification:** I perfectly understand why and what are getters, setters and access modifiers. I just want comprehensive answer for a certain question above.

Comment: How to edit my question? I didn't find the answer. I know the differences between public and private. But I want some examples when public, protected, default field is better then private plus get and set.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve complete encapsulation in `java` by making members of a class `private` and access them outside the class only through `getters` and `setters`. Although a lesser degree of encapsulation can be achieved by making the members `public` or `protected`.

Comment: I understand it. But what are the cases when It's better to use any access level except private?